# What Operations are not supported in Sqlite Database?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have heard that Stored Procedure is not supported in Sqlite DB. is it true ? what are the other operations that are not supported by Sqlite? Which other Db we can use for Iphone?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html

Answer (score 2):

> I have heard that Stored Procedure is
>   nt supported in Sqlite DB

That is true.

> what are the other operations that are
>   not supported by Sqlite?

In order to achieve simplicity, SQLite has had to sacrifice other characteristics that some people find useful, such as high concurrency, fine-grained access control, a rich set of built-in functions, stored procedures, esoteric SQL language features, XML and/or Java extensions, tera- or peta-byte scalability, and so forth.

http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

> Which other Db we can use for Iphone?

SQLite is one of the better choices.